# Trying to hide a part of the url with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to hide a part of an url from the address, 
because it's useless mouse coordinates sent due to `input type="image"`

The URL is:

```
www.example.com/search.html?mode=fulltext&query=HelloWorld&ssubmit.x=0&ssubmit.y=0
```

I want to hide the ssubmit.x and ssubmit.y part.
I tried adding the following rule to .htaccess, but without success:

```
RewriteRule &ssubmit[\.]x=[0-9]+&ssubmit[\.]y=[0-9]+$  [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don’t you just omit the name for that image submit button?

Comment: Why don't you use a POST, which won't attach the parameters to the URL?

Comment: @Borealid because of `REST` principes, because I want linkable search results, because I'm not creating anything with this form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) can only check the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) but not the query. You need to use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to check the URL query, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?ssubmit\.x=0&ssubmit\.y=0(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^search\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

But it is probably better if the *ssubmit.x* and *ssubmit.y* do not get into the URL. One solution would be to omit the name of the image submit button.

Comment: Of course, omitting `name` did the trick, don't know how I did not see this, thank you.